# How to hook the DOM loaded event?

Tags: html, dom, load

Can someone point me in the direction to hook the DOM loaded event?

Basically, i want to display a loader while the dom is loading (I dont mean Ajax requests- the first time a user hits a page) ?

Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of the popular Javascript libraries have a "DOM loaded" event you can use for this.

Essentially:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    // if using jQuery
    $(document).ready(function() { $('#loading').hide(); });
    // if using Prototype
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() { $('loading').hide(); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loading">Loading...</div>
    <!-- rest of page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 31):

If you're not using a framework, use the DOMContentLoaded event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Great! Mozilla has a nice doc on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternative to jQuery, YUI Event provides an [onDomReady()](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#ondomready) function for this purpose as well.  Here's the example from their site:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function init() {
    YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle("hidden_element", "visibility", "");
 }
 YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(init);

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this without a library (and really, even with a library, since you're dealing with script blocking and IE unpredictability) is to put a script at the very end of the page:

onLoaded = function(){ ... }

onLoaded()