# Chrome Javascript security?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

So i have this empty page,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            console.log(container);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and for some reason console.log returns "null" instead of div object. But when i put code onto some website like jsfiddle, it works.
How do i fix this, is it a common problem?

Comment: Short answer is because your div doesn't exist yet. Your script code is run immediately, rather than waiting for the page to finish loading.

Comment: If you put that exact code into jsfiddle, the console would output `null` (http://jsfiddle.net/Ruq8P/) so is that what you're expecting to get ?

Comment: Also, [This stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8996894/877472) has some good information relating to script execution order which illustrates what I and vcsjones are talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSFiddle may not mimic DOM loading correctly. The problem with your example is your JavaScript is executed before the DOM is completely loaded. The DOM is loaded top-down, so when your JavaScript is executed, the `container` div doesn't exist in the DOM yet.

You can move your script block after your `div`, that's a quick way to resolve the issue. Alternatively, you can listen for an event for when the DOM is loaded, then execute your code. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582437/how-to-hook-the-dom-loaded-event) demonstrates how to do that.